# conditionalPanel in shiny based on number of items in inputSelect

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to implement a `conditionalPanel` based on the number of items in a `selectInput` dropdown box.

I can get the condition to work when it is based on the value of the dropdown as per the following (the `textInput` field allows you to set the number of items in the dropdown):

```
runApp(
  list(ui =  fluidPage(
    textInput("in_number", "number",1),
    uiOutput("dropdown"),
    conditionalPanel("input.dropdown >= 3", p("show some stuff"))
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {

    output$dropdown <- renderUI({
      selectInput("dropdown","My Dropdown", c(1:input$in_number))
    })
  }
  )
)
```

However if I change my `conditionalPanel` to be:

```
conditionalPanel("input.dropdown.length >= 3", p("show some stuff"))
```

then it doesn't work. I do get an error message in the developer tools console saying *"Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"*

I assume it is something to do with how shiny defines the dropdown items.

EDIT: to clarify my needs.
Is there a way to do the javascript condition that will allow me to assess the number of items in the dropdown, rather than assessing the value of the dropdown?

Comment: There's no error message if you do `input.dropdown !== undefined && input.dropdown.length >= 3`. The error occurs because `input$dropdown` is `NULL` before it is rendered. But `input$dropdown` is the selected value, not the number of items, so you'll never get `input.dropdown.length >= 3`.

Answer (score -1):

I know what you mean now. I would suggest you use the `shinyjs` package and its `toggle` functionality to do what you want.

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
runApp(
  list(ui =  fluidPage(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    textInput("in_number", "number",3),
    uiOutput("dropdown"),      
    p(id = "mydiv", "show some stuff")
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$dropdown <- renderUI({
      selectInput("dropdown1","My Dropdown", c(1:input$in_number))
    })    

    observe({
      toggle(id = "mydiv", condition = as.numeric(input$in_number) >= 3)
    })
  }
  )
)
```

[image]

Comment: The original code does work to manage the `conditionalPanel` based on the value of the dropdown. That isn't my issue. My issue is I can't do it based on the number of items in the dropdown. If the dropdown has more than 3 items in it i want to 'show some stuff' regardless of the value selected.

Comment: @Dan, the code above is doing exactly what you want! It will show the `show some stuff` with any value greater or equal to 3 in the `"My Dropdown"`

Comment: Read my original comment and edit to my question. My original code did that too, without your recommendation of the quotes around the 3. I am not interested in the value of the dropdown showing the `conditionalPanel`. I want to show the `conditionalPanel` based on how many elements the user can choose from. Not the value of those elements.